# Download file from HTTP response NodeRed

Tags: javascript, http, node-red

In Node-Red, I'm trying to call an API that provides me with a csv file full of data, I make a http request and get the following return:

```
{
"_msgid": "60d0351dcf215557",
"payload": "",
"topic": "",
"headers": {
    "content-length": "0",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-type": "text/csv",
    "date": "Fri, 13 May 2022 07:48:51 GMT",
    "server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
    "access-control-expose-headers": "Request-Context",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "expires": "-1",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "request-context": "",
    "x-frame-options": "DENY",
    "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=Report_20180520_0000_20180720_2359.csv",
    "x-node-red-request-node": "3a8a1b06"
},
"statusCode": 200,
"responseUrl": "https://somewebsite.net/api/analytics/report/someID/file",
"redirectList": [],
"retry": 0,
"url": "https://somewebsite.net/api/analytics/report/someID/file"
```

My question is, how do I actually get to download the *Report_20180520_0000_20180720_2359.csv*?
Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files content would be in the `msg.payload` but looking at that response the file returned by the server was empty.

This can be seen by `msg.payload` being empty and `msg.headers.content-length` being `0`